# Group by a result of case statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by, case, aggregate

I'm trying to get a query with an aggregate function and case statement to work in my select and a group by on the case statement to work in SQL Server 2005 but I seem to be missing something.

```
declare @td int
set @td = 20130731

select 
    count(*) as total,
    case
       when dateadd(s, cdm.[StartTime], '19700101') >= '2013-07-31 00:00:00.000' and dateadd(s, cdm.[StartTime], '19700101') < '2013-07-31 01:00:00.000' 
        then '0-1'
    end as timestripe
FROM 
    [EXTERNAL_CDR].[dbo].[CDRMAIN] as cdm
WHERE 
    cdm.LocalDay = @td
    AND cdm.targetnum IN ('500','600')
GROUP BY
    timestripe
```

The `count(*)` part is a little weak, I know but the problem is with the group by statement. When I run this query, I get the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Invalid column name 'timestripe'.

It seems that the case statement is the root cause of the error but I shouldn't have to write a subquery or join just to get this to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference an alias in the GROUP BY, so just put the entire case statement in it. Leave the "as timestripe" part off.

```
declare @td int
set @td = 20130731

select 
    count(*) as total,
    case
       when dateadd(s, cdm.[StartTime], '19700101') >= '2013-07-31 00:00:00.000' and dateadd(s, cdm.[StartTime], '19700101') < '2013-07-31 01:00:00.000' 
        then '0-1'
    end as timestripe
FROM 
    [EXTERNAL_CDR].[dbo].[CDRMAIN] as cdm
WHERE 
    cdm.LocalDay = @td
    AND cdm.targetnum IN ('500','600')
GROUP BY
    case
       when dateadd(s, cdm.[StartTime], '19700101') >= '2013-07-31 00:00:00.000' and dateadd(s, cdm.[StartTime], '19700101') < '2013-07-31 01:00:00.000' 
        then '0-1'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

For this query, [logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) is:

- FROM,
- WHERE
- GROUP BY and
- SELECT.

Because `SELECT` comes after `GROUP BY` all aliases defined in `SELECT` clause (including `timestripe`) can't be used in previous step (`GROUP BY`).

One solution could be:

```
SELECT x.timestripe, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM (
select 
    case
       when dateadd(s, cdm.[StartTime], '19700101') >= '2013-07-31 00:00:00.000' and dateadd(s, cdm.[StartTime], '19700101') < '2013-07-31 01:00:00.000' 
        then '0-1'
    end as timestripe
FROM 
    [EXTERNAL_CDR].[dbo].[CDRMAIN] as cdm
WHERE 
    cdm.LocalDay = @td
    AND cdm.targetnum IN ('500','600')
) x
GROUP BY x.timestripe
```

Comment: This query will generate at most two rows: one for `0-1` and, maybe, one row for `NULL` timestripe.